# Typescript React compiler issue with children props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, wordpress-gutenberg

The Typescript compiler seems to be having an issue recognizing JSX child elements as the `children` prop. I am trying to use Typescript for Wordpress Gutenberg block development but am running into this odd issue.

**Error**

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & Props'.
> Property 'children' is missing in type '{ title: string; }' but required in type 'Props'.

The error occurs on the `edit.tsx` file at `<PanelBody title="Some Title">`. For whatever reason the child element does not satisfy the `children` props for the `PanelBody` element. I can trick the compiler by adding children as a prop to get it to compile without errors:

```js
<PanelBody children={null} ...>
  <p>Child</p>
</PanelBody>
```

But, VS Code gives me an error that says `children` is defined twice....rightly so. But the compiler doesn't understand this and only sees one children prop here. Any reason why that is?

**edit.tsx**

```js
import { BlockEditProps } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import { InspectorControls } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { PanelBody, Panel } from "@wordpress/components";

import React from "react";
import { BlockAttributes } from "./metadata";

const TestBlock: React.FC<BlockEditProps<BlockAttributes>> = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InspectorControls>
        <Panel>
          <PanelBody title="Some title">
            <p>Some child element</p>
          </PanelBody>
        </Panel>
      </InspectorControls>
      <div>
        <p>This is some content. Maybe it needs a child?</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestBlock;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const defaultConfig = require("@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config");

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: "./src/editor/index.ts",
    module: {
        ...defaultConfig.module,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            ...defaultConfig.module.rules,
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        ...defaultConfig.resolve,
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },

    output: {
        ...defaultConfig.output,
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/editor"),
    },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/wordpress__block-editor": "^6.0.5",
    "@types/wordpress__blocks": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/wordpress__components": "^19.3.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/block-editor": "^8.2.0",
    "@wordpress/blocks": "^11.2.2",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^22.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears I followed some either bad or old advice on how to add Typescript support to Gutenberg block development.

Its really as simple as just using `@wordpress/scripts` without any configuration.

I removed all the custom stuff I did in the webpack config file as I was probably overriding and over doing some rules.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const defaultConfig = require("@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config");

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: "./src/editor/index.ts",
    output: {
        ...defaultConfig.output,
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/editor"),
    },
};
```

The scripts package has `typescript` support built in so no need to manually add that functionality yourself.